# figuring out suspension at systemd level in Debian

Tags: debian, power-management, suspend, hibernate

Sometimes back I followed the guide at https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend which gives/shares the following command -

```
$sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Now while it gives the command to enable hibernate and suspend again, it doesn't give anything to check what the state.

Is there a command to check if hibernate and suspend are on or not ?

Answer (score 3):

`sudo systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target` will tell you the status of all of those targets. If it says the're masked, then you've disabled them with `systemctl mask`.

You can check for all masked files using `systemd-delta -t masked`. In general, `systemd-delta` is useful for telling you what local configuration you've done to systemd; see its manpage for details.

You can also check for the symlink in `/etc/systemd/system`; `systemctl mask` works by creating a symlink to `/dev/null`. So `ls -l /etc/systemd/system | grep '/dev/null'` is a quick, though not 100% perfect, way to see what is masked on the system if for some reason `systemd-delta` doesn't work.

Comment: I got http://paste.debian.net/787687/ and -

`$ systemd-delta -t masked
0 overridden configuration files found.`

Does it mean that that no configuration files have been changed on my lappy ?

Comment: @shirish that should mean they're not currently masked. You can test it easily—just mask one of them, then confirm systemd-delta says so, then un-mask it to restore the state before you tested it.